# find -name with and without xargs give different result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I'd need to perform some operations on a lot of files in a lot of dirs, say checking whether they are password protected or not.

I've created a bash script (fileproc.sh) and I'd want to check if it works so I did a silly thing just to see if it works:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'File: ' + $1
```

Then if I run a simple

```
find . -name "*.zip" -type f
```

I have a long list of .zip files as expectd.

If I run

```
find . -name "*.zip" -type f -print0 | xargs ./fileproc.sh
```

I have only three files.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Use `xargs -0` with `print0` and use: `echo "File: $1"` in script

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is used to run the command with more than one argument, see `man xarg`. It will append the lines printed by `find` to the command line until a system-dependent limit is reached.

`$1` is just the first command line argument, you don't see the second and following arguments.

In your script try

```
echo 'File(s): ' "$@"
```